# Html5 audio element can't read blob url

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I'm using Asp.Mvc and recorder.js to capture audio from the view, converting the resulting blob to url using

```
Url=Url.createobjecturl(blop);
```

Then sending the url to the server.

Now the problem is when I send the url back to the client and try to play it in an audio element as its src,it gives a 404 not found error.

Your thoughts please...

edit:

my code goes like this:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (canvas) {
        dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();
        recorder && recorder.exportWAV(handleWAV.bind(this));

        recorder.clear();
        fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("audio",  audioUrl);
        fd.append("id", id);
        fd.append("drawing", dataUrl);
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/Session/UploadData", true);
        xhr.send(fd);

    }
}, 100);
```

I'm sending the canvas drawingUrl and the audioUrl to the server and get them both again in another view like this

```
setInterval(function () {
if (ctx) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Session/DownloadData/" + id
        })
    .done(function (data) {
        x = data;
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.src = data["drawing"];
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
        audioElement.src = data["audio"];  //error thrown here
        audioElement.play();
    });
}, 100);
```

the canvas drawing appears fine, the audio doesn't though.

forgot to mention that the error happens only after sending the url and getting it back from the server, however it works fine if I played the url directly in the page before without it, and yes the url comes back from the server with the same value as sent.

Comment: My first thought is that you haven't shown enough code. And the code you have shown isn't valid. However, at a guess, BLOB URLs are only valid until the document is unloaded - sounds like you're taking the user away from the page

Answer (score -2):

```
function display(vid){

    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(vid);

}
```

Comment: The method cannot accept Html nodes